# Find the number of occurences of a pattern based on a condition on success match index

Tags: regex, string, perl, pattern-matching

I have a long string, containing alphabetic words and each delimited by one single character ";" . 
In perl, how to count the number of occurences of a pattern (delimited by ";") if index of a success match is dividable by 5.

Example:

```
$String = "the;fox;jumped;over;the;dog"
$Pattern = "the" 

OUTPUT:  1
```

In above case, the $Pattern "the" exists as the first and 5th words in the $String and both matches are delimited by ";" . However; the output result would be 1, since only the index of second match (5) is dividable by 5.

If possible, I am wondering if there is a way to do this with a single pattern matching without using list or array as the $String is extremely long.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Non-Regex Solution

The simplest solution to this problem is likely to break it up into steps and not use a regex at all.

The following splits the string based off the delimiter and then filters based off every 5th element:

```
my $string = "the;two;three;four;the;six;seven;eight;nine;ten;eleven;twelve;the;fourteen;the;sixteen";
my $pattern = 'the';

my $i = 0;
my $count = grep {(++$i % 5) == 0 && $_ eq $pattern} split /;/, $string;

print $count, "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
2
```

#### Partial Regex Solution

It's also possible to create a regex that will pull every 5th word from the string.

The below takes advantage of the fact that a capture group in a repeated pattern will only match the final repetition.

```
my $count = grep {$_ eq $pattern} $string =~ /(?:([^;]+)\b;?){5}/g;
```

#### Full Regex Solution

You asked for a single regex solution though.

The following accomplishes that, but is easily the most complicated and therefore the most fragile solution:

```
my $count = () = $string =~ /\G(?:(?:[^;]+\b;?){5})+?(?<=(?|;($pattern)|\b($pattern);))/g;
```

Of the three, I would definitely recommend the first method.  It's the easiest to understand at a glance and therefore the easiest to maintain and adapt in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Miller. Very comprehensive solutions. I am wondering how to make them work if my $pattern had a lookaround inside: let's say instead of it being 'the' , suppose it was 'the(?=six;)'

Comment: That modification to your spec is kind of meaningless without more context.  You original spec reeks of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Just because one likes regular expressions, doesn't mean they are the best tool as demonstrated above.  To answer your question, of course it's possible to include a more complicated pattern for matching, but one needs to inspect why they want a lookahead before committing to any answer that would involve one.  In other words, it's another potential XY Problem without additional context.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a regular expression by just iterating over the words.

```
my @words = qw( the fox jumped over the dog );

# A long string
my $string = join ';', map { $words[ rand @words ] } ( 1..10000 );
my $pattern = 'the';
my $position = 5;

my $count = 0;
my $matches = 0;
foreach my $token ( split /;/, $string ) {
    next if (++$count % $position);
    $matches++ if $token eq $pattern;
}

print "There are $matches instances of '$pattern' showing up with an index mod 5 = 0.\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

@Miller, I was not able to add comment under your answer; so I am adding here.

Sure. Let me elaborate on the context a bit then. First of all, my tendency to use regex is more about convenience rather than interest; as in my home project I am trying to focus and spend my time more on the actual process, not coding.

Please note that my question(s) are all about real problems not just some fancy ones.  Being exposed to programming, but not that much experienced in regex in perl, once I raise the questions,  I am trying to see how the regex/perl experts would solve them, then I would grasp the idea, and tweak the answer for other problems down the road.

The flat files I am processing are 10s of GB and I need to do thousands of iteration on every run. I have multi-threaded the code to use all my pc's 8 cores. On every run, I need to use a new regex towards the solution to the problems. My needed regexes are mostly around counting,  look-arounds, and conditions on match found positions/indexes. Conditions could be as complicated as a degree n polynomial equation on the match found positions/indexes. The ever-changing part of the code would be just the Condition criteria which I would eventually rather treat it as a variable parameter provided as an ARG to the .PL code file.

Now more about the Search and Condition criteria:

```
Let :
"P" be the match found position; and,
"I" be the match found index.
```

As an example, the following would be one of the Search and Condition criteria:

```
Search criteria: the(?=six)

Condition criteria: 3×P^4 - 4×I^3 - 1 is dividable by 7 .
```

This reads as: Count the number of "the(?=six)" provided that 3×P^4 - 4×I^3  - 1 is dividable by 7

What I need to know is how powerful regex in perl is to solve these types of problems; and if it is not indeed, then I will inevitably go another route.

I hope I have provided a better sense of what I refer as "convenience" and "my tendency to use regex".